# How to do filtering option like this?

Tags: plugins, filters, content

I'm developing a site for my client and he gave me this site for reference. I'm wondering if anybody can help me with how to do the filtering like this with a plugin. Thanks.

https://entrepreneurs.unltdindia.org/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.